# Socket.remoteAddress doesn't update after reconnection with different IP

Tags: node.js, sockets, node-webkit

I am writing NWJS application which communicates with measuring sensors over TCP. I am using one socket instance. When connection is established (connect event), I use remoteAddress property to display IP address of sensor I am currently connected to.

Problem:

- I connect to sensor on IP address let's say A, both remoteAddress and _host socket properties are correct.
- I disconnect sensor using socket.destroy()
- I connect application to another sensor on IP address B and then the problem shows up - remoteAddress property shows wrong former address A but _host property shows B

Minimal steps to reproduce (interactive nodejs console):

```
 net = require('net')
 socket = new net.Socket()
 socket.connect("192.168.0.20", 1028)

 //socket.remoteAddress is 192.168.0.20, socket._host is 192.168.0.20, 

 socket.destroy()

 //later
 socket.connect("192.168.0.17", 1028)

 //socket.remoteAddress is 192.168.0.20, socket._host is 192.168.0.17
```

I can probably solve this issue by making new instance of sensor socket every time or using _host property, but would like to discuss the reason of this behaviour (bug?)

Comment: I think socket instance is not intended for re-use as such, after `destroy()` is called. Try using a `new net.Socket()` each time. Documentation say about `onDestroy`: "Ensures that no more I/O activity happens on this socket".  But in your example it does not throw any error to enforce this.

Comment: Yes, good point. I have read the docs for `destroy` function many times, but I understood it like it's almost time same as `end`, but ensures that no more data will be received. Never actually thought it means don't use it again. Thank you.

Comment: Still, NodeJS "should" throw an error if re-using a destroyed socket. That to me sounds like a missed implementation detail in nodejs API.